# Stop Dreamweaver from creating a local site

Tags: dreamweaver

This may be an unusual request but - Dreamweaver likes to create a local cache of the site you are working on. I like to just keep everything on the server and, especially now that I'm using a (small sized) SSD, I would like to stop DW from downloading all the image/sound/movie/style etc files whenever I get a file from FTP. If I could get it to just use temporary files and delete them when I've saved/sent them to the server that would be perfect.

Common sense tells me there is a checkbook or other option to do this simply but, I've scoured the preferences extensively and I'm just missing it I guess.

can anyone whose been here before shed some light on the situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from my extensive research, this can't be done -_-

You can click 'disable related files' in the general preferences section but that won't stop it from maintaining a site cache.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try with below information

Best practice is usually to use two. It's not good to treat your website server like a fileshare by working on the live files on the server. You could easily break your website while you're working on it.

CS5 has acknowledged this by removing the option to work directly on the live files.

Dreamweaver has always promoted having a full local copy of what's on the server.

The idea is that you edit the local files, preview them and test them. Rinse, repeat. Once they're tested and validated, you then upload them to the server.

The local files can double as backup for the remote files.

https://forums.adobe.com/message/3138517